# How can I insert a variable on an element's attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, attributes

I would just like to to ask if its possible to insert a jQuery variable on an attribute. Here is my sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {

   var url = 'http://www.google.com';
   var data = '?one=1&two=2&three=3';

});

</script>
</head>
<body>    
      <a href="jquery var">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to put the jQuery var value of the href. How can I do that?
Thank you in advance. ;)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com Learn it. Love it. Live it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.

```
$(function() {

   var url = 'http://www.google.com';
   var data = '?one=1&two=2&three=3';

   $('a:first').attr('href', url + data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I know how to assign a variable on the anchor attribute but I want to hardcode the exact variable on the <a href="jquery var should be put here"></a>. Do you think it is possible? It should be something like in PHP, where you can changed the values using $_POST..

Comment: @madzman23, Please give me an example of what would go in the `href` attribute.

Comment: Assuming we declared the value of the var. here is what I want to put on "HTML" code: <a href="url+data">Click Here!</a> i want to put the hardcoded value of the href because I need to open the href using thickbox modal and I need to pass value on the page I call. Of course it works with your solution .attr() but I need to complete the href for the thickbox modal. I really dont know if its possible and how can I do it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Jacob's answer is what you want.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't give the output I needed. Anyways, thank you for your answers, I already fix the problem using a server script and assigned it to the href. I think jquery is not capable of doing that because serverside and clientside is on different realm. ;)
regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to associate more complex objects with an element:

```
$(function() {
    // Store data...
    $('a:first').data('jQuery', { a: 1, b: 2 });

    // Then retrieve it later...
    alert($('a:first').data('jQuery').a);
});
```